# Minimum IELTS score for Danish immigration

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, ielts, language-test, danish-citizens

As per this [link](http://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/work/greencard-scheme/language-tests.htm), it requires to have IELTS score  6.5 to gain 20 points.

There is no clear information about overall band score or score per ability.

Is it the overall band score 6.5 ? or

Is it the score per ability?

Comment: Can somebody help me here?

Comment: It looks like nobody here knows--why not email them? I checked some Danish universities. They just listed 6.5 as well (no info on whether that's the average or for each ability). Sorry!